# only first line of wp_enqueue_style gets executed

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to build a child theme for an existing theme someone else built. That theme uses multiple stylesheets and of course, I want the child theme to enqueue them all.

Strangely enough I noticed that that only the first line of the wp_enqueue_style() of the parent theme gets executed while the wp_enqueue_style() of the child theme does work.

I'm kinda stuck and I have no clue on how to make the child theme use all those stylesheets.

```
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    //parent style
    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    //enqueue css of the parent theme
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/css/custom-login.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/css/font-dc-cash.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/css/font-dccash.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/css/hro-admin.css' );

    //enqueue css of the child theme
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

btw: I know that those css files dont't make any sense. Tell that to the original builder.

[download link of the parent theme](https://www.scouting.nl/downloads/ondersteuning/communicatie/websitetools-templates-en-teksten/templates/4158-wordpress-template-scouting-nederland/file)

Comment: Is this a publicly available theme or a custom-built one? If it is publicly available, linking to it will help in finding a solution.

Comment: here is the download link: https://www.scouting.nl/downloads/ondersteuning/communicatie/websitetools-templates-en-teksten/templates/4158-wordpress-template-scouting-nederland/file

Comment: It seems you need to use the same stylesheet name as the parent theme. In this case that would be `thema-style` for the main stylesheet, `google-fonts-style` for the google fonts stylesheet, etc. Just use the same script names that are used in the parent theme. I referenced the [Wordpress Child Theme documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to `wp_enqueue_style()` needs to be unique.  You are passing in `$parent_style` for everything.  If you give them all unique names, maybe using `$parent_style` as a prefix, it should fix it.

Comment: Thanks! I will remember it next time.

Answer (score 1):

Give first parameter a name, a unique one so in that way you can enqueue all of them.

Based on wordpress codex:
`wp_enqueue_style( string $handle, string $src = '')`

> $handle
>   (string) (Required) Name of the stylesheet. Should be unique.

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    //parent style
    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    //enqueue css of the parent theme
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_login', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/css/custom-login.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font_awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font_dc_cash', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/css/font-dc-cash.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font_dccash', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/css/font-dccash.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'hro_admin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/css/hro-admin.css' );

    //enqueue css of the child theme
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version') );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```